# Tizen get incoming notyfication

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk

How to get incoming notyfications on tizen werable (watch). For example emails, sms.

This dont work:

```
var notifications = tizen.notification.getAllNotifications();
var index = 0;

for (index = 0; index < notifications.length; index++) {
      console.log(notifications[index].id);
console.log(notifications[index].title);
}
```

Comment: Did you add permission <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/notification"/>

Comment: Yes I have this privilage. Maybe I misundertood something. When the notyfication comes to my watch for example email or sms, This peace of code should grab all notifications what Im having and displayed right?

Comment: It retrieves all previously posted notifications.

Comment: So it should work properly. For clarity when the notyfication come to watch for example mail from gmail an displayed on the watch because of the default behavior of apps installed on my watch I should still get the all notyfication what comes from that piece of code?

Comment: Maybe I need to develop a companion app?

Comment: I think you should if it need.

Answer (score 1):

**General application can NOT get notification of other applications due to security issue.** Special applications ONLY have the privilege for it. e.g. pre-loaded w-home application which is in charge of the wearable home screen.

**Application can only get notifications of own application as it is mentioned in official reference guide.**

> **To retrieve a previously posted notification, use the getNotification()** method of the NotificationManager interface (in mobile and wearable applications with the notification ID as a parameter:

[Notifications - Tizen Developers](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/notifications?langredirect=1#manage)